# In my UITableView, how can I reset the "selected cell color" back to default upon selection?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    checkRequirements() { () -> Void in
        var room = self.rooms[indexPath.row]
        self.roomForPreview = room
        self.indexPathForPreview = indexPath
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(CONSTANTS.SegueLobbyToRoomPreview, sender: self.view)
    }
}
```

I perform a segue when a user selects a cell, but when I unwind, I find that the cell still has a grey background.

How can I make the cell grey only on touch? Once the touch is gone, the cell goes back to normal color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`deselectRowAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    ...
```

If you're using a `UITableViewController`, you can set the [`clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewController/clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear) property to `true` - this will work as well.